# bigNumber not parsing ether properly

Tags: javascript, typescript, numbers, ethereum, ether

I have the following:

```
import { BigNumber } from "@ethersproject/bignumber";
import { parseUnits } from "@ethersproject/units";

const decimals = 18;

export const add = (a: string, b: string): string => {
  const _a = parseUnits(a, decimals);
  console.log(_a.toString(), a);
  const _b = BigNumber.from(b);
  const res = _a.add(_b).toString();
  return res;
};

// a = 123456789123456789.123456789123456789
// b = 1
// _a.toString() = 123456789123456789123456789123456789
// res = 123456789123456789123456789123456790
```

Am I missing something obvious as to why `res` wouldn't be calculated as "123456789123456790.123456789123456789"?

Even if I don't pass in `decimals`, it's still the same result. (Ideally I wouldn't want to specify an actual decimals value)

Answer (score 15):

The `BigNumber` is actually a BigInteger (you can't have decimal values in it). This is because on the Ethereum blockchain, numbers are represented as 256 bit integers. You can also see [my answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99660/a-object-returned-for-public-uint256-instead-of-integer-when-calling-a-contract/99664#99664) to the same topic.

Now working with decimals could be confusing let me put it this way:

```
// creating BigNumber instances
const a = ethers.BigNumber.from('1') // creates BigNumber of 1
const b = ethers.utils.parseUnits('1', 18) // Creates BigNumber of 1000000000000000000
const c = ethers.utils.parseEther('1') // same as above, by default 18 decimals

a.toString() // '1'
b.toString() // '1000000000000000000'
ethers.utils.formatEther(a) // '0.000000000000000001'
ethers.utils.formatEther(b) // '1.0'
```

If you're mostly dealing with currency numerics having decimals, then you can simply stick with `parseEther` and `formatEther` utils.

If you're not working with currency and it's still a BigNumber then you'll can use `BigNumber.from()` and `value.toString()`

Comment: can you explain why if we're not working with currency that we can use BigNumber.from()? For instance if I try to `ethers.BigNumber.from("21.33")` it fails. I haven't figured out why yet